# Сломалась номерация списков в Sphinx Documentation generator

Tags: sphinx

Я хотел создать простую страничку документации с использованием Sphinx. На странице должен распологаться список команд с описанием для установки модуля. Как я понял, Sphinx автоматически нумерует списки при следующем синтаксисе:

```
#. Один
#. Два
#. Три
```

Результат:

```
1. Один
2. Два
3. Три
```

Я хотел чего-то подобного, но со вставкой команд между пунктами:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но нумерация поломалась:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нумеровать вручную не хочется. Подскажите, как починить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все оказалось просто, добавить отступы:

```
#. Установить виртуальное окружение:

   ``python3 -m venv venv``

#. Активировать виртуальное окружение:

   ``source venv/bin/activate``

#. Установить зависимости:

   ``pip install -r requirements.txt``

#. Запустить автоматическую сборку и локальный сервер командой:

   ``sphinx-autobuild source build``
```